# How to attach a URL link to a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a WP site, www.glitzyla.com and I want to attach a URL link to the button on the hero image, but for some reason it just will not work.

This is the code I currently have and the download_link is in phpmyadmin

```
<button><type="" onClick="<?php echo get_custom('download_link'); ?>" target="_blank" class="">download ios app</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your source indicates you don't have an anchor tag `<a>` within your button. You're also not linking to anything as your destination URL is within an `onclick` action. Your link should be set up as followed:

```
<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/glitzy-organic-manis-pedis/id1111503407?ls=1&amp;mt=8" target="_blank" class="">download ios app</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap You can use Following Code to create link on Button. [Buttons](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/)

```
<a href="<?php echo get_custom('download_link'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" role="button">download ios app</a>
```

Also Check out This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error with your HTML code.

You should use the type attribute **inside** the HTML element like this:

```
<button type="">download ios app</button>
```

If it doesn't work, you can try warping the the button with `<form>` tags.

Here is an example:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.apple.com/">
    <button type="submit">Apple</button>
</form>
```